# regular circuit breaker doesn't trip.....when changed out to ground fault breaker it trips

Tags: electrical

circuit from wall socket keeps tripping even with a small fan with a ground fault circuit circuit so took out the ground fault circuit breaker and put in a regular breaker now the fan works but I need to and need a ground and need a ground fault why does the groun ground fault  keep tripping tripping

Comment: Maybe you'd like to proof-read this question just once more.

Comment: Either the GFCI breaker has gone bad or more likely you have a ground fault.  If you haven't already I'd buy a new breaker and if it doesn't solve your problem, return it.

Answer (score 2):

GFCI breakers trip if either:

- there is an overload
- there is a ground fault

Regular breakers trip if:

- there is an overload

From here we have a simple high school logic question.   If a regular breaker does not trip, and a GFCI breaker does trip, what kind of fault condition are we talking about?

Right first time :)

So now you need to find and kill that ground fault before it finds and kills you.

Answer (score 0):

If a GFCI is tripping, either it is defective or you have a short somewhere. Assume the latter, trace the wire, find it, fix it. Note that it may be in something plugged into that circuit.